# How to delete a dinamically allocated struct? (c++)

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, delete-operator

(About a hour ago I asked something about my code and accidentally deleted the post instead of editing it. I'm sorry for those who kindly answered to me. However, since I edited my code and partially fixed the issue, I'd rather ask for the new deal here.)

I have a class, and I have a struct inside my class. Since I want to be able to print its content, I overloaded the `ostream` operator:

```
struct packetarray {

    const value_type *pktarr;
    positive length;

    packetarray() : pktarr(0), length(0) {}

    packetarray(value_type *v, positive l) : pktarr(v), length(l) {}

    ~packetarray() {        
        delete[] pktarr;
        pktarr = 0;
        length = 0;
    }


    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const packetarray &p) {

    os << "[ ";
    for (int j = 0; j < p.length; ++j) {
        os << p.pktarr[j];
        if (j < (p.length - 1)) {
            os << ",\t";
        }
    }

    os << " ]";

    return os;

    }
};
```

with `value_type` being `typedef T` for my template class.
I have a method, `packet`, which returns a `packetarray` object:

```
packetarray* packet(positive y, positive x) {


    try {

        if (y >= this->y || x >= this->x) {
            throw OutOfBounds();
        }

        value_type *v = new value_type[this->z];
        for (int z = 0; z < this->z; z++) {
            v[z] = this->operator()(z, y, x);
        }

        packetarray *p = new packetarray(v, this->z);
        v = 0;
        return p;


    }
    catch (const OutOfBounds &e) {
        std::cout << e.message() << std::endl;
        packetarray *p = new packetarray();
        return p;
    }



}
```

As you can see, when I write `value_type *v = new value_type[this->z]` I allocate memory on the heap, memory which is later supposed to be freed. However, since this memory is shared with the `pktarr` pointer of my `packetarray` struct, I can't free the memory unti I safely returned (and printed) the content of my `packetarray` object.
My intention (expectation?) was to delete that part of memory in the `packetarray` destructor -- but even if I actually create a `packetarray` object on the heap by writing `packetarray *p = new packetarray(v, this->z)`, no destructor is being called at the end of the program. So, how am I supposed to free the memory I need to allocate in order to initialize my `packetarray` object?

(For those who are wondering what my class does: it's basically a 3-dimentional array and the `packet` method returns a data structure which contains all the elements at a certain (y, x) position for every plane z.)

Comment: You `delete` everything you `new`, and you `delete[]` everything you `new[]`. But instead of `new[]` and `delete[]`, why not use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)? And instead of `new` and `delete`, why not use plain simple *objects* instead of pointers? Or if it's a requirement to use pointers, why not a smart pointer like [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr)?

Comment: If you are having troubles with lifetimes of objects with *dynamic storage duration*, why not explore *Smart Pointers*?

Comment: unrelated: your useage of the words "struct" and "class" suggest that you believe a struct is something different than a class. This is not the case. C++ has only classes. The only difference between a class declared with the keyword struct or class is their default access specifiers

Comment: I can't use any container class, because this is an assignment from my teacher.

Comment: So you try to implement a container?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to implement my own container class.
By the way, I don't think I can use smart pointers for two reasons: 1) we didn't study smart pointers during the c++ course, and even if we did, 2) I was specifically asked to return a packetarray object, but if I use a smart pointer I'd end up with returning a smart pointer object.